# How do I access a variable outside of a proc

Tags: variables, scope, global-variables, tcl

I'm trying to wrap my head around Tcl variable scopes, but I'm stuck on what I thought would be a simple concept: how can I access a variable that I've defined outside of my proc, but that I do not explicitly pass to the proc?

I'm trying to avoid setting a bunch of global variables, and only access variables that I define within a particular namespace.  What do I need to add to my code below so that the proc can access the variable `a`, which is obviously not in the scope of the proc?

```
set a apples
proc myList {b c} {
   puts [concat $a $b $c]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`upvar`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/upvar.htm):

```
set a apples
proc myList {b c} {
    upvar a a
    puts [concat $a $b $c]
}
```

Or, expanding the example a bit to show the "source" variable does not have to exist in the global scope:

```
proc p1 {} { set a 10; p2 }
proc p2 {} { upvar 1 a b; puts "in p2, value is $b" }
p1
```

outputs

```
in p2, value is 10
```

---

If `a` was defined in a namespace, you can use [`variable`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/variable.htm):

```
namespace eval foo {
    set a apples
    # OR
    # variable a apples
}

proc foo::myList {b c} {
    variable a
    puts [concat $a $b $c]
}
```

Or if `a` was created in the global scope, you can still access it without the `global` function, using `::` (I'll reference [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33441093/1578604) for this one):

```
proc myList {b c} {
    puts [concat $::a $b $c]
}
```

Comment: Don't want to step on your toes: expanded the upvar example.

Comment: It's usually considered bad form to `upvar` to a variable in a caller (especially a procedure or method) whose name wasn't explicitly given to you; it greatly reduces the reusability of the code and makes everything far more fragile.